# How to type chinese using an English keyboard?

Tags: pinyin, software

I'm trying to learn the Chinese language using ChineseSkill for Android. There are some sections / steps within the lesson that ask me to translate the English sentence to Chinese, but I don't have a Chinese keyboard. When I input something so I can pass the step, it shows the expected answer and there it has shown how I should have typed the sentence in. For example `nǚ` is typed in with `nv3`. There is a Pinyin chart within the program but I couldn't figure out how to encode the symbol. I don't want to use websites or online tools because I don't want to leave the program as it also gives score based on time and it keeps running. Is there some sort of table or chart for this?

Comment: You need an IME, input method editor. There are plenty of them available for most system, including android. Check your language settings on your phone/tablet, or google to find and install one. E.g. here is one (not necessarily the best, just to give you an impression, what an IME is): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.pinyin&hl=en

Comment: @DrunkenMaster I've installed Google Pinyin but there It does not convert `nv3` to `女` it understand `nv` and converts it to `女` but then adds `3` next to `女` or `女3`.

Comment: Of course, pinyin IME is fuzzy, it doesn't require you to remember the tone, just type, like 'meinv' for 美女 or try 'mn', or 'mnv'. In many cases, multisyllable words can be entered with their initials only, e.g. 中国 with 'zhg', etc. Experiment.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster ok but I prefer doing it exactly that way or one symbol for one thing because this is confusing and difficult to memorize and will make one prone to mistakes. Is there a way to stop this? once I'm comfortable I might go back to how it is right now but it's my second day only :)

Comment: @Barracuda I don't know any input methods that you insert the tone. You just have to deal with the fact that it just doesn't. You will have to type "nv" and then select the "nv" character you want.

Comment: FYI, if you want to insert tone, you can try zhuyin-fuhao (bopomofo). Every input method for zhuyin-fuhao requires you to insert tone. It is not the same system as pinyin though, but you can look up [this table](http://www.erva.nl/zhuIn-hanIn.pdf) to get the one-to-one correspondence between pinyin and zhuyin-fuhao. [This system](http://crptransfer.moe.gov.tw/pinyin_05.aspx) allows you to convert from one to the other.

Comment: @EnricoBrasil Well it really sucks! For example today I tried to enter `bái lí` using Google Pinyin keyboard the first word was correctly converted to Chinese `白` but for the second word I had to scroll a long list of very similar symbols to find the correct one which is`梨`. It's the second day of my journey and I'm facing a huge problem trying to type a sentence correctly. It wasted a lot of my time and lowered my score (Kill me! but my OCD needs perfect score!) so It was really frustrating and every tutorial online explains Pinyin not how to optimize it or suggest a better alternative.

Comment: @Barracuda A good point in searching through a long character list is that you will certainly improve your character reading! ;) The symbols in the begining do look similar, but you'll get used to it.

Comment: Are you trying to type in a character into the app, or are you trying to type in `nǚ`? Or are you trying to type in `nv3`? The way you word it, it sounds like the app is asking for `nv3` as an answer.

Comment: Agree that bopomofo seems to be the only imput method with tones. Once you learn it, it's slightly faster than raw pinyin, and more accurate on the whole too. No phonetic input system is perfect. The only way you're going to be able to input characters accurately first time without choosing from a list is installing wubixing, dayi, or some other input by radical (where you type out the shapes of the characters). Of course, this doesn't use phonetics at all, but is the only method which you can count on for accurate results every time

Comment: As for which IME to use, sogou is by far the best for accuracy of pinyin. It doesn't take in tones, but its accuracy for finding the right characters first time is **much** better than any other IME on the market. Kylxyz has links to their IMEs in their answer. Asides from accuracy, it's also actually easier to use than other IMEs in my experience, and it looks nice and is customizable ; )

Answer (score 3):

try to use "[Sougou pinyin for Windows(exe)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Pdbl10NONMOFN1S2hLcGc5cTQ/view?usp=sharing)",

for Linux use "[Sougou pinyin for 32bit Linux(deb)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Pdbl10NONMMlpCdHJCRWhLQnM/view?usp=sharing)"

or "[Sougou pinyin for 64bit Linux(deb)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Pdbl10NONMWU1razJYU2FvZE0/view?usp=sharing)"

or "[Sougou pinyin for Mac OS(dmg)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Pdbl10NONMY3M3dTUzRVM1eFU/view?usp=sharing)"

or "[Sougou pinyin for Android (apk)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Pdbl10NONMaDhsMWllQUNHSWc/view?usp=sharing)"

Comment: Do you have installation instructions for Ubuntu/Debian? I have tried installing the .deb file previously and it didn't work.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster for Linux I would recommend the open source input method Rime. You can apt-get all the components. An instruction is here: https://github.com/rime/home/wiki/RimeWithIBus

Comment: @DrunkenMaster, pal, would you please show me your OS version, bcz, the .deb file is for Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04, I guess your OS version was old. If so.. try this http://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/help.php,   this is an installiation manul in chinese, however they put images to explain, I think you can understand. Good luck

Comment: @Kylxyz Definitely not, I always update to the latest Ubuntu version, when it becomes available. And this is the exact manual I have tried to follow, but ended up with nothing being installed. No IME at all.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster,  No IME? may I take this as you cannot install any other input method, or only canot install Chinese?  If  only Chinese, maybe you should check about to add Chinese IME in ubuntu....

Comment: @DrunkenMaster, By the way, actually I am using iBUS Chinese pinyin input, on Ubuntu 14.04, It works good..... though it is not as conveinent as Sougou IME,

Answer (score 0):

Where are you? If you buy your phone in China, it will come with Chinese input! I use ibus IM on my laptop, it's good. There is probably a version for Android.

Comment: definitely not in China. I know that would make no sense otherwise but with todays technology one should not find it so difficult to write in any language they desire.

Comment: Search Google Pinyin on Play store. It's one of the best Pinyin IME.